# Can't implement asmack api

Tags: android, asmack

I have following code in android using asmack api for gtalk app

```
            ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(
                    HOST, PORT, SERVICE);
            
            XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);

            try {
                connection.connect();
                SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN", 0);
            } catch (XMPPException ex) {
                Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Failed to connect to "
                        + connection.getHost());
                Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
                setConnection(null);
            }
            try 
                connection.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
                Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                        "Logged in as " + connection.getUser());

                
            } catch (XMPPException ex) {
                Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Failed to log in as "
                        + USERNAME);
                Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
                setConnection(null);
            }
```

and I am getting this error while running the app on AVD

> Failed to connect to talk.google.com
>
> XMPPError connecting to talk.google.com:5222.: remote-server-error(502) XMPPError connecting to talk.google.com:5222.
>
> -- caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to talk.google.com/ip address of my server (port 5222): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

Comment: Are you sure you have the INTERNET permission for your app?

Comment: yes, INTERNET permission is already there.